# Zip mono/flux with another that depends on the one I own

Tags: java, kotlin, mono, flux, reactor

I want to zip two monos/fluxes, but the second one (the one I'll zip) is dependand from the first that I already own.
For example:

```kotlin
//...

    fun addGroup(
        input: GroupInput
    ): Mono<Group> = Mono.just(Group(title = input.title, description = input.description))
        .flatMap { g -> groupsRepository.save(g) } // Gives me back the new db ID
        .zipWith(Mono.just(GroupMember(g.id /* <-- ??*/, input.ownerId, true)))
        //...

// ...
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You need to use flatMap in that case. What do you need zip for?

Answer (score 2):

I would say no. You can only zip things that can run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

you could use map or flatmap in this case, is there any reason you need to use Zip?

Answer (score 0):

No, your code cannot even compile because variable `g` belongs to the lambda inside the `flatMap()` call.
`zipWith()` is not intended for this use case, use `map()` or `flatMap()`